# css file is not loading on the page

Tags: html, css

www.septembris.lv 
Css file is not loading, I can't find out why.

There is a code in html:

```
<base href="http://www.septembris.lv/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
```

File itself opening from the browser:
http://www.septembris.lv/assets/css/style.css

Comment: share html file

Comment: What should it look like? Your CSS is being loaded, but you are not setting the font for example. Can it be that you are missing a stylesheet?

Comment: your css is loading but there is an error in a js file

Comment: Open up web console and see if it's actually being included properly and not 404'ing?

Comment: seems like part of the file disappeared

Answer (score 1):

`assets/css/style.css` is loaded without any problem

I think the problem is `bootstrap.min.css` not be loaded, so the website looks like broken.

Comment: bootstrap code is inside that file, so all file is not loading.
Even if I put all css inline in html - styles are not loading

Comment: thanks, part of the file disappeared... ok, thanks a lot

Comment: @NadezdaGurska you only include `bootstrap.min.js` file,  you should also include `bootstrap.min.css` in html